# Como cerrar correctamente un sesión de Facebook con Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-api

en esta ocasión estoy trabajando con Firebase integrando el inicio de sesión con Facebook, el detalle que tengo es que cuando cierro sesión al parecer la sesión de Facebook no se esta cerrando correctamente ya que me aparece un dialog donde me dice si deseo cerrarla cuando regreso a la activity del login. Este es mi código de la clase donde manejo el login y logout de Facebook:

```
package com.discomsc.eqbe;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.discomsc.eqbe.libs.Utils;
import com.discomsc.eqbe.models.Usuario;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.ServerValue;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;


public class FacebookSignIn extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "FacebookLogin";
    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private String option;
    SharedPreferences prefsUsuario;
    DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook_sign_in);
        mDatabase = Utils.getDatabase().getReference("cat_usuarios_app");
        prefsUsuario = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        option = extras.getString("option");
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.loginFacebook);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
        loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
            }
        });

        if(option.equals("login"))
            loginButton.performClick();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser != null)
        {
            if(option.equals("logout"))
            {
                mAuth.signOut();
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);
        showProgressDialog();
        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
                            Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
                            usuario.setId_usuario(user.getUid());
                            usuario.setEmail(user.getEmail());
                            usuario.setProveedor(user.getProviderId());
                            usuario.setN_usuario(user.getDisplayName());
                            usuario.setActivo(true);
                            usuario.setF_reg(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP.toString());
                            usuario.setF_login(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP.toString());
                            String device = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
                            mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).setValue(usuario);
                            mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).child("dispositivos").child(device).setValue(token);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(FacebookSignIn.this, "Error al iniciar sesión, intente nuevamente más tarde",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        hideProgressDialog();
                    }
                });
    }

    public void signOut() {
        mAuth.signOut();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog == null) {
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Procesando...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        }

        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Posteriormente cuando regreso a esta activity en vez de que me inicie sesión me pregunta que si deseo salir de la sesión actual de Facebook siendo que se supone ya esta cerrada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una duda, por que haces el login con Facebook separado de firebase en vez de usar el proveedor propio de Firebase?

Comment: como separado? bueno es que me base de la documentación de Firebase para hacer el login con Facebook

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenia el mismo problema y encontré la solución ya que no me manda el dialog, agrega:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

En tu botón de cerra sesión e intenta otra vez, ya no debería mostrarte el dialog de sesión iniciada, espero poder ayudarte. Saludos

Jersso Melanio Diaz Santa Cruz

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que cerrar ambas sesiones de esta manera:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilice en mi aplicación lo siguiente:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class));
                finish();
```

Y con esto comprobé si había usuario

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        goMainScreen();
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva amigo, a mi si me funcionó, si alguien mas ve esto, DE NADA

Código de goMainScreen para pasar a otra activity

```
private void goMainScreen() {
    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class));
}
```